# php rawurldecode doesn't produce same string passed to rawurlencode

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to be able to have spaces and parentheses in a URI segment of my site's URLs (the segment is used for DB queries). So, I `rawurlencode()` a string and then `rawurldecode()` the same string in the receiving page, however it's not entirely the same. The spaces are fine but parentheses are left in their hex char codes. Which completely messes up my database queries. Any idea why `rawurldecode` isn't producing the EXACT string which was passed to `rawurlencode()`?

the original string = Compton Community College (CA)

the encoded string =

```
  Compton%20Community%20College%20%28CA%29
```

a vardump of the decoded string is

```
  string(38) "Compton Community College (CA)"
```

in the view page source

```
  "Compton Community College &#40;CA&#41;"
```

*edit*

alright, so apparently this might be a Codeigniter thing (which I'm using). The code

```
<a href='<?php echo site_url('college/'.rawurlencode($player['college'])); ?>'>
```

produces the correct url of `http://localhost/ff/index.php/college/Compton%20Community%20College%20%28CA%29`

The final URI segment is recieved as a parameter in the following function

```
function view_college($college = FALSE)
{
    if($college === FALSE)
    {//no college provided
        redirect('');
    }
    $college = rawurldecode($college);
```

And at this point the string is already in the form displayed above. So maybe I'm screwing something up or just can't expect CI to correctly pass the string. :-( Thoughts?

Comment: Can you post sample strings you're encoding/decoding? I cannot replicate parentheses-not-decoding via `rawurldecode()`.

Comment: Your issue doesn't lie with `rawurldecode()`; the characters in your "view source" are HTML-characters - something URL encoding wouldn't touch (nor can it be replicated). Can you post the code you have that manipulates the strings (encoding/decoding/echoing), and also list what browser you're using? `htmlentities()` and `html_special_chars()` do not encode parentheses either - so this is a fun one!

Comment: @newfurniturey Perhaps not as fun since it looks like it might be a result of the framework. sorry :-/

Comment: PHP automatically decodes parameters for you.  You rarely if ever need to explicitly call `rawurldecode`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use IDs (for SEO reasons maybe), you can add another field to the db - web url, and write a web-safe version of the college name... In your example it could be something like **Compton-Community-College-CA** or even lowercase.

Full url:

```
http://localhost/ff/index.php/college/Compton-Community-College-CA
```

[CodeIgniter's URL Helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html) has a nice function for that: **url_title()**.

Answer (score 0):

**No No No. Do not do that. What a headache!**

Put all of your colleges in a database and use an auto-incrementing integer `id` column to drill into it's content:

If you put a HTML `<base>` element inside `<head>` to define your root:

`<base href="http://localhost/yourapp/">`

Then you can write it VERY SIMPLY:

`<a href='college/<?= $id;?>'><?= $name;?></a>`

Will essentially render code that will act like:

`<a href='http://localhost/yourapp/college/5'>Some Community College</a>`

---

**Update 1:** After @Frank Farmer's comment, I advise keeping the auto-incrementing `id` field, but retract using this in the URL. Rather, programmatically generate a separate alpha-numeric SEOid and use it instead for search engine optimization. Same basic link construction.

Comment: Including a proper slug in the URL, rather than just a numeric id is preferable for SEO purposes.  Limiting the characters in the slug to alphanumeric is definitely preferable though

Comment: Thanks for noting that @FrankFarmer :)

Answer (score 0):

A little late but happend to me and I found this solution.

The problem is in the **_filter_uri** function of **URI** class of CI. This is what they do in that function:

```
// Convert programatic characters to entities
$bad    = array('$',        '(',        ')',        '%28',      '%29');
$good   = array('&#36;',    '&#40;',    '&#41;',    '&#40;',    '&#41;');

return str_replace($bad, $good, $str);
```

So you have to invert that and then apply **rawurldecode**:

```
function view_college($college = FALSE)
{
   if($college === FALSE)
   {//no college provided
      redirect('');
   }
   $bad = array('&#36;',    '&#40;',    '&#41;',    '&#40;',    '&#41;');
   $good   = array('$',     '(',        ')',        '%28',      '%29');

   $college = str_replace($bad, $good, $college);
   $college = rawurldecode($college);
```