# Parentheses passed in url break codigniter query

Tags: codeigniter, url, activerecord, urlencode

I have a string being passed via an URL to a Codeigniter driven site. The string is urlencoded before being passed, then urldecoded by the controller before being passed to a function in the model that searches for the string in a database table. I've read several other posts/articles on this, but none offer a viable (for me) solution to the issue. Here are some of the things I have read:

[URL having parentheses not working in codeigniter with datamapper ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14466096/url-having-parentheses-not-working-in-codeigniter-with-datamapper-orm)

[Parenthesis issue in codeigniter url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17445869/parenthesis-issue-in-codeigniter-url/17445904#17445904)

[php rawurldecode doesn't produce same string passed to rawurlencode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150319/php-rawurldecode-doesnt-produce-same-string-passed-to-rawurlencode)

http://qubitlogs.com/PHP/2013/01/24/parentheses-in-urls-not-working-codeigniter-datamapper-orm/#.U0MtAce7mxa

And here is what is happening:

An url encoded string gets passed via an url, like so:

`http://www.awebsite.com/controllername/functionname/test%28string%29`

The controller handles this like so:

```
public function functionname($string) {
    $this->load->model("codeigniter_model");
    $dstring = urldecode($string);
    $validString = $this->codeigniter_model->valid_string($dstring);        
    if (!$validString) { 
        $thiserror =  "<br>Error: Invalid String. (".$dstring.")"; 
        echo $thiserror; 
        exit;
    }
}
```

And the model:

```
function valid_string($string)
    {
    $sql = "select id from dbtable where dbfield = ?"; 
    $query = $this->db->query($sql, array($string));
    //Added this in to see what the query actually end up being
    echo $this->db->last_query();
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) :
            return TRUE;
        else:
            return FALSE;       
        endif;
}
```

The echoed query is correct: select id from dbtable where dbfield = 'test(string)' and when run in Navicat returns the proper id. However - Codeigniter returns FALSE on the query.

I have also checked that the string in the query getting echoed does NOT contain HTML entities.

I have no control over the string being passed and really need Codeigniter to accept ( and ) as part of the string.

Thoughts, anyone?

EDIT: When the same string is passed to the Codeigniter controller via a post from a form, it works properly.

EDIT #2: Just tried creating the query using the Active Record method as suggested here: CAN'T ADD ANOTHER LINK SO : ellislab.com forums viewthread 162036

This:

```
$this->db->select('id');
$this->db->where('dbfield', "'".$string."'", FALSE);
$query = $this->db->get('dbfield');
```

does not work either.

EDIT #3: Thanks to Kyslik for suggesting using profiler.  The string is apparently being html encoded after all: select id from users where string = 'test&#40;string&#41;' which, of course WOULD return false because of the HTML entities.

Unfortunately, adding code to remove those entities using both a regular query and an active record query:

`$sql = "select id from dbtable where dbfield = ?"; 
$query = $this->db->query($sql, array(htmlspecialchars_decode($string)));`

AND

`$this->db->select('id');
$this->db->where('dbfield', "'".htmlspecialchars_decode ($string)."'", FALSE);
$query = $this->db->get('dbtable');`

still do not work.

Comment: Please turn on [profiler](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/profiling.html) `$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);` and see yourself what query is beeing sent to the database server.

Comment: +1 to @Kyslik for suggesting enabling profiler. It led to the actual solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that htmlspecialchars_decode() does NOT decode the entities for ( and ). If I add this code to the controller before passing the string (and AFTER url decoding):

`$dstring = str_replace("&#40;", "(", $dstring);
$dstring = str_replace("&#41;", ")", $dstring);`

Then everything works as it should.